# Making a magnitude legend via GMT

Tags: windows

I'm using GMT(Generic maping tools)and I'm making a map of the seismicity of my area. I'm using psxy to show the seismic points but I can't figure out how to make a legend for the magnitude. I am using the pslegend command but I can't figure out how the input textfile should be. Can anyone help me?